# Process not killed after completion in linux using python

Tags: python, linux, process, multiprocessing

I have a python program that has a limit of 10 processes running at a time. When the 11th process comes in, it waits until other processes are finished. In MS Windows environment, the process terminates itself when their task is finished and other processes are able to run. But in the Linux environment, the processes are not terminating even after their task is done?

Do I have to clear/kill the process in some way?

```
for processIndex in range(0, noOfProccesesToRun):
    dataToProcess = inputData[0:fileSize]
    inputData = inputData[fileSize:len(inputData)]
    curObject = ImportCclToMixPanel(dataToProcess)
    process = Process(target=curObject.importData)
    if currentProcess:
        childProcesses = currentProcess.get_children(recursive=True)
        while len(childProcesses) >= MAX_PROCESSES:
            childProcesses = currentProcess.get_children(recursive=True)
    process.start()

 def importData:
     //do stuff
     print "exiting
```

Using python version 2.7.5

Comment: please add the python version

Comment: Are you calling the `setrlimit` syscall...?

Comment: No, I am not what does that call do?

Comment: See [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) man page and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Ok, that will set the limit for the process of how many resources it can use, but main question is why does the process not terminate when it completes, instead goes to a zombie state

Comment: Then read first the wikipage about [Zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) ... You should call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)